# google play console json file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-console

I go into my google play console api access. When I try to create a service download a json in google cloud platform my json key file will not download to my macOS?

I try to download it and I see no json key. I is anyone have the same prob? I use macOS Ventura.